# iPad: Why missing photos when sync photos and video using iTunes with my Mac

Tags: ipad, photos, data-synchronization

I have photos around 3021 and 91 videos on my Mac but once I sync with my iPad. The photo collection in iPad only have 2938 photos and 91 photos. My Mac still have 3021, how to I sync all the rest of the photos?

At the moment, if I tried to sync, It has nothing to sync.

Comment: Is this something that is stuck for a few days or a week? If you add one more item to each - do either of those sync either way? How are you syncing precisely? iCloud or WiFi or USB and iTunes? Please consider editing in either some info on versions and how you sync if the other questions don't seem relevant

Comment: I reset my iPad. I plug into my Mac with cable and sync via iTune. In iTune, I display the drop down menu by point to my iPad and Sync

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using iTunes sync.

1. From iTunes menu bar, click View, References, Advanced, Reset warnings, Reset cache
2. Restart iTunes
3. Sync

Answer (score 0):

Not working here.
Also thousands of errors in the iPad log when syncing from iTunes:

> assetTransfer: failed to sync asset